# Determine whether or not the following sequence converges. If so, find the limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Im not sure if I am evaluating the convergence of the following sequence correctly, and I am unsure of how to determine the limit. All help is greatly appreciated.

$a_n = {1 \over (\sqrt{n^2-1}-\sqrt{n^2 +n})}$

My attempt at the convergence:

$ {1 \over (\sqrt{n^2-1}-\sqrt{n^2 +n})} < {1 \over n} $

$ \lim_{x\to \infty} {1 \over n} = 0$

Therefore, ${1 \over (\sqrt{n^2-1}-\sqrt{n^2 +n})}$ converges to as $ {n \to \infty} $

Comment: If $x_n< y_n$ and lim $y_n$ exists, then it does not imply that lim $x_n$ exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{n^2-1}-\sqrt{n^2+n}}
=\frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}+\sqrt{n^2+n}}{-1-n}
=\frac{n(\sqrt{1-1/n^2}+\sqrt{1+1/n})}{-1-n}.
$$
And this does not tend to 0, but...

Comment: I am still unsure of how to complete the limit. Should L'Hopitals rule be applied?

Comment: @Username19: multiply the rightmost expression by $\;1=\frac{\frac1n}{\frac1n}\;$ and apply arithmetic of limits. The result is almost immediate.

Comment: @Username19 I've added one more step. Then , e.g. dividing by $n$ should give the final limit.

Comment: $-({\sqrt{n^2-1} \over n} +{\sqrt{n^2+n} \over n}) = -(1+1) = -2 $ ?

Comment: @Username19 Near. I assume that you remember about $-n-1$.

Comment: I eliminated the denominator, simplifying it from ${(-n-1) \over n}$ to $-1$

Comment: Your result is right, @Username19 : the limit is $\;-2\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

$$\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2+n}}\le\frac1n$$

which is true...but perhaps not in the way you meant: your secuence is *negative*, so if you want to use the squeeze theorem this is not the way.

Kola's answer shows you the way to reach the actual limit.

Answer (score 0):

We have: $\sqrt{n^2-1} - \sqrt{n^2+n} = (\sqrt{n^2-1} - n) - (-n +\sqrt{n^2+n}) = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1} + n} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}} + 1} \to -\dfrac{1}{2}$. Thus $a_n \to -2$.